# Is there a way to change the layout/style when a user zooms in a plotly line chart?

Tags: javascript, plotly

The documentation for plotly is a bit hard to use and couldn't find a specific settings for relayout on zoom.

The method I used is to add a 'plotly_relayout' event listener and then check the event data if it has 'xaxis.range[0]'. If it does then I make some update and then do a relayout and restyle.

```
var gd = document.getElementById(chart_id);
gd.on('plotly_relayout', function (eventdata) {
  // Check if a pan or zoom occurred.
  if (eventdata.hasOwnProperty('xaxis.range[0]')) {
    layout_update = {...,...};
    trace_update = {...,...};
    Drupal.plotly.relayout(chart_id, layout_update);
    Drupal.plotly.restyle(chart_id, trace_update);
  }
}
```

This might be an inefficient way of going about it, though. It seems to be a bit slow. Also it cannot differentiate between a pan and a zoom action as the event data is the same. Is there a better way?